# JQuery Datatable in Angular Js Ng-Click not Working?

Tags: angularjs-directive, datatables

I have a DataTable and I am loading it using Angular Js, I have Created a directive and wrapped my DataTable in this directive, A common approach of wraping  JQuery Plugin in Directive so that it can live in `Angular Digest Cycle`.
But the `ng-click` that is on button and coming from `render Function of column` in datatable is not `clickable` (Not Working, Angular did not compiled it). Is there any way to make it `Clickable`. I know the approach in which we use `{{}} with ng-repeat`to populate data in datatable. I'm looking a `directive way`, so you can tell me what is stoping ng-click from working or how to make my directive right! Please stick with directive approach. Code is following.

```js
App.directive('jqtable', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E, A, C',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        var dataTable = element.dataTable(scope.options);
         scope.$watch('options.data',  handleModelUpdates, true);
            function handleModelUpdates(newData) {
            var data = newData || null;
            if (data) {
                dataTable.fnClearTable();
                dataTable.fnAddData(data);
            }
        }
    },
    scope: {
        options: "="
    }
};
```

});

And here is my Controller:-

```js
$scope.options = {
   aoColumnDefs: [{
        "bSortable": true,
        "aTargets": [ 1],
        "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
            if(meta.col==1){
                return data+" <a class='btn btn-sm btn-default' ng-click='showalert()' >Click me </a>"
            }
        }
    }],
    bJQueryUI: true,
    bDestroy: true,
    data:$scope.data                        
};
$scope.showalert=()=>
{
    alert("Angular Compiled the Html");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular does not know you have injected elements to the DOM. You must `$compile` each row. You can do that in [**`rowCallback`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback). Since DataTables may inject new rows when the table is filtered, sorted or upon page change, you can add a `compiled` flag to prevent rows from being $compiled multiple times :

```js
$scope.options = {
  rowCallback: function(row) {  
    if (!row.compiled) {
      $compile(angular.element(row))($scope);
      row.compiled = true;  
    }  
  }
  ...
}
```

see **http://next.plnkr.co/edit/KxwqSVXIogtXYx4I**

Comment: Thanks but i already solved problem and its in `pure Angular JS` way. I appreciate your help.` drawCallback function`  seems interesting.
And also when using angular Js one should not rely on Jquery because its not a good approach to cut shortcut.I hope you will understand from where I am coming. And kindly explain `drawCallback function`.It's a new way to invoke `compile function` to me. I hope you won't mind investing your time in explaining how it actually works in browser.

Comment: @ahsanayub, I have altered the answer completely. Sorry for the confusion (I am nnormally using angular datatables). I realized that `drawCallback` is a no go since you will end up having rows $compiled' `n` times. Use `rowCallback` instead and set a flag on each row when it is compiled. DataTables injects and removes rows to and from the DOM all the time, so `drawCallback` is not very useful.

Comment: The solution i came up with was, Let the table populate and then invoke `$compile function` to run the `$digest` again. Though, its rare in angular but it becomes necessary if you are using `Jquery plugins` and adding something to DOM dynamically.  Thanks for creating plunker, it really helped me, understanding the idea behind your approach. I accept your answer, Thanks! @davidkonrad

Comment: @ahsanayub, Thank you for accepting the answer, but if you have a better answer  I think you should post that answer and mark that as accepted instead.  Perhaps it will help future visitors

Comment: your answer is better! Its simple and approachable. I would have posted my answer but i think it will only make people confuse and its also requires a bit of tuning.